# Finding subitems of an item found through JQuery's eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery, find

I'm trying to accomplish the following, but I think my syntax is wrong. Are you not able to find subelements of an element found with eq()?

```
$('.excerpt_expander').click(function(){
    clearInterval(run);
    $(".feature_text_item").eq(item_count).find('.feature_excerpt').hide();
    $(".feature_text_item").eq(item_count).find('.feature_full_text').show();
});
```

Comment: maybe, if you're trying to access the last item, you want `item_count - 1`?

Comment: your jQuery looks a bit strange for what you're trying to do. Can you show your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/nzTFd/

Comment: you're right - the problem lay elsewhere - in that the actual position of each item was shifting in the sort order, so item_count referred to a different thing each time. Thanks though.